# Mobileiron: iOS App authorization in Active Directory

Tags: ios, authentication, xamarin, active-directory, mobileiron

We are developing an iOS application in Xamarin, which will be distributed via MobileIron. We are also developing the Backend WebServices (rest).

What I need to know is, when a web service call comes to my API, I want to make sure, that the call is coming from a client who is logged-in to my app with his Active-Directory credentials, using MobileIron.

The MobileIron website has plenty of information, but is also a bit chaotic.

- What MobileIron products are needed for my use case?
- Whats the best way to protect my WebServices and allow just requests from our iOS Application with correct AD-Credentials?
- Do I need the AppConnect SDK or can I just wrap the iOS Application in MobileIron? If I need the SDK, are there any examples?

Thanks in advance!

Cheers
Immi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way how it should work, we have this built up in our environment.
Assuming that the target devices are managed by the MobileIron MDM system with MobileIron Core (MDM) & MobileIron Sentry (Gateway -> Intranet).
You can configure MobileIron Sentry in this way, that a webrequest from an AppConnect enabled app (no matter if SDK included or wrapped!) will be authenticated with user certificate from device, Sentry obtains Kerberos ticket from domain controller for the user and then forwards the web request to a website / webservice where Kerberos authentication is enabled and the user has access granted.
There are many things to configure for this to work (CA, user certificate -> device, service account with delegation configured in AD, SPN for website configured in AD,...) and there is a good support document available from MobileIron to make this up & running.
It's to extensive to describe here all steps.
If this is already setup in the target environment (if there is already another AppConnect app), there are only a few steps left (SPN and MI app-specific AppConnect Config).

The good news is, that the app itself does not have to take care of the authentication. The MobileIron stuff does this on its own...